# Как остановить сервер Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть простой сервер, который запускается отдельным процессом:

```
def startServ(pipe):
    Process(target=taskServer, args=(pipe,)).start()

def taskServer(pipe):
    host = ""
    port = 50005
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind((host, port))
    sock.listen(10)
    connectedClients = []
    while True:
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        print(addr, "is connected")
        connectedClients.append(conn)
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        dataUnpack = pickle.loads(data)
        print(dataUnpack)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    (firstpipe, secondpipe) = Pipe()
    root = Tk()
    btn = Button(root, text="start server", command=lambda: startServ(secondpipe))
    btn.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно его тормознуть при закрытии основного окна программы?
Можно ли ему через Pipe() какой-то сигнал послать? Вроде такого:

```
def startServ(secondpipe):
    ...
    while True:
        stopSignal = pipe.recv()
        if stopSignal: break
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        print(addr, "is connected")
        connectedClients.append(conn)
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        dataUnpack = pickle.loads(data)
        print(dataUnpack)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        (firstpipe, secondpipe) = Pipe()
        root = Tk()
        btn = Button(root, text="start server", command=lambda: startServ(secondpipe))
        btn.pack()
        root.mainloop()
        firstpipe.send("stop")
```

Но почему-то кажется, что после запуска его сразу же заклинит на строке

```
stopSignal = pipe.recv()
```

Так как он будет тупо ждать данные из трубы.

Comment: простой способ: установить `daemon` атрибут у `Process` (оставляя за кадром рациональность смешивания `multiprocessing`, `socket`, `tkinter` APIs здесь).

Answer (score 1):

Если установить `daemon` атрибут, то процесс будет убит при выходе программы:

```
def startServ(pipe):
    Process(target=taskServer, args=(pipe,), daemon=True).start()
```

Если хочется мягко завершить процесс, то можно `Event` использовать:

```
def taskServer(stopped):
    while not stopped.is_set():
        "цикл сервера"

stopped = multiprocessing.Event()
...
stopped.set() # ask the server to exit
```

В этом случае, тело цикла не должно блокирующих на долго операций иметь, например, `sock.accept()` следует вызывать только, если select/poll вернули в списке для чтения сокет, на котором вы слушаете входящие соединения. [Пример кода](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5308168/4279)—добавьте `timeout` параметр в `select()` вызов.

Альтернативно, можно по сигналу выходить, так называемый [self-pipe трюк](https://cr.yp.to/docs/selfpipe.html): при получении сигнала пишем в pipe, которую проверяем на чтение в том же процессе в основном цикле с select/poll:

```
import signal

def taskServer():
    input_fd, output_fd = os.pipe2(os.O_NONBLOCK | os.O_CLOEXEC)
    read_set = [input_fd]
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM,  lambda signum,frame: os.write(output_fd, b'\0'))
    # ...
    server_socket.listen(10)
    read_set.append(server_socket)
    while True:
        readable, writable, errored = select.select(read_set, write_set, [])
        for fd in readable:
            if fd is input_fd: # got signal to exit
                os.read(input_fd, 1)
                # cleanup...
                break # exit the loop
            elif fd is server_socket: # new connection
               client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
               read_set.append(client_socket) # get ready to read client's request
            else:
                "..."
```

На Windows, [`socket.socketpair()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31881115/4279) вместо pipe можно использовать.

Конечно, не обязательно по сигналу просить сервер выйти, можно просто установить новое соединение и послать команду на выход.

Это достаточно низкоуровневый код, в зависимости от конкретной задачи можно библиотеки более высокого уровня использовать.