# Параллельные задачи в Python 3.x: две функции выполняются последовательно, а не параллельно

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Добрый день, осваиваю  Python и не совсем понимаю как сделать следующую вещь: на экране крутится надпись

```
Loading...\|/-
```

Функция идентификатор занятости допустим: `def indentify():...` , а в это время параллельно идет другой процесс копирования файлов, разархивация и т.д. функция `def do_smth():...` и как только `do_smth()` закончил свою работу он передает сообщение в консоль `well done`, заканчивает работу и тем самым останавливает выполнение функции `def indentify()` и передает управление обратно в `__main__` который продолжает дальше делать то, что надо?

Пример того как я пытался это реализовать, но код выполнялся последовательно,а не параллельно:

```
from threading import *
import time

def count_numbers():
    start_number = 1
    while start_number < 1000000:
        start_number += 1
        print(start_number)
    return start_number

def spinning_flash2 ():
    coursor = '/-\|'
    while True:
        for i in coursor:
            line = 'Loading... ' + i
            print(line, end = '\r')
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    thread_counter = Thread(target=count_numbers()).start()
    thread_counter = Thread(target=spinning_flash2()).start()
```

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Параллельное выполнение функций в разных классах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/654031/23044)

Comment: стоит заметить, что помещение функции типа `count_numbers()` в фоновый поток не позволит вам улучшить производительность за счёт использования нескольких CPU ядер: чистый Питон в любой момент только один поток исполняет, см. [Почему так медленно? Зачем тогда потоки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/702448/23044)

Comment: в тему: [Параллельное исполнение двух функций python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/704612/23044) и [Нужна ли многопоточность, чтобы показывать прогресс долговыполняющейся функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/564768/23044)

Comment: Тут основная цель задачи не ускорить, а продемострировать индикатор работы пользователю, что бы у него не возникло вопроса - Зависло? или работает? и он не прервал выполнение программы.

Comment: комментарии и ссылки не только и столько для вас, а для посетителей из гугла с похожей проблемой (основная аудитория Stack Overflow -- больше 90% трафика из поисковиков).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучший вариант для интерактивной программы - это когда интерфейс контролирует выполнение операции, а не наоборот. Так можно поймать прерывание от пользователя и корректно завершить процесс.

```
from threading import *
import time

def count_numbers():
    start_number = 1
    while start_number < 1000000:
        start_number += 1
        #print(start_number) #портит всю картинку
        time.sleep(1)
    return start_number

def spinning_flash2 (thread_counter):
    coursor = '/-\|'
    while thread_counter.is_alive():
        for i in coursor:
            line = 'Loading... ' + i
            print(line, end = '\r')
            thread_counter.join(1)
            if not thread_counter.is_alive():
                 break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread_counter = Thread(target=count_numbers)
    thread_counter.start()
    try:
        spinning_flash2 (thread_counter)
    except:
        pass
        #Вот тут написать код для завершения треда.
    thread_counter.join()
```

С простым тредом через target обработчик повесить сложно. Можно попробовать с `threading.Event`.

Answer (score 6):

Обратите внимание, что в этих строках:

```
thread_counter = Thread(target=count_numbers()).start()
thread_counter = Thread(target=spinning_flash2()).start()
```

у вас происходит не передача функций `count_numbers` и `spinning_flash2` в класс `Thread`, а их вызов и передача их результата в `Thread`. Поэтому сначала полностью выполнится одна функция, в `Thread` передастся ее результат, потом полностью выполнится вторая функция, и опять в `Thread` передастся ее результат.

Чтобы выполнялось правильно, нужно убрать скобки после имен функций `count_numbers` и `spinning_flash2`:

```
thread_counter = Thread(target=count_numbers).start()
thread_counter = Thread(target=spinning_flash2).start()
```

Comment: Спасибо, это я понял. а как теперь закончить def indentify(): - возможно ли как то ему передовать сигнал об окончание?

Comment: @ДмитрийГорчаков: такие вещи лучше отдельным вопросом задавать. Можно `daemon=True` атрибут установить, чтобы поток/процесс автоматически завершился при выходе из программы. Ещё для потоков можно `threading.Event()` использовать. Есть `multiprocessing.Event()` для отдельных процессов, [пример кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/525972/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите этот пример из книги "Python - к вершинам мастерства" и почитайте книгу ;)

```
import threading
import itertools
import time
import sys

class Signal:
    go = True

def spin(msg, signal):
    write, flush = sys.stdout.write, sys.stdout.flush
    for char in itertools.cycle('|/-\\'):
        status = char + ' ' + msg
        write(status)
        flush()
        write('\x08' * len(status))
        time.sleep(.1)
        if not signal.go:
            break
    write(' ' * len(status) + '\x08' * len(status))

def slow_function():
    time.sleep(3)
    return 42

def supervisor():
    signal = Signal()
    spinner = threading.Thread(target=spin, args=('thinking!', signal))
    print('spinner object:', spinner)
    spinner.start()
    result = slow_function()
    signal.go = False
    spinner.join()
    return result

def main():
    result = supervisor()
    print('Answer:', result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Обратите внимание на два обратных слеша, это экранирование

Comment: правильней было б в фон уводить медленную функцию, а не интерфейс пользователя. зачем целый класс сигналу - непонятно..)

Comment: почему правильно хеви в фон - потому как эта функция получит сигналы от пользователя. например, контрол+с. где именно выполнится это прирывание неизвестно и корректное завершение получается невозможно.

Comment: @eri Это пример из книги и я привел его как есть, и написал название книги, считаю это может быть полезным

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо. Опираюсь на код eri и другие, написал решение удовлетворяющее условиям задачи:

```
import threading
import time

def slow_f():
    time.sleep(5)
    print('End of slow func...')
    return 42

def spin (msg, thread_for_slow_f):
    coursor = '/-\|'
    while thread_for_slow_f.is_alive():
        for i in coursor:
            print(msg, i, end = '\r')
            time.sleep(0.1)
            if not thread_for_slow_f.is_alive:
                break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread_for_slow_f = threading.Thread(target=slow_f)
    thread_for_slow_f.start()
    spin('Loading...', thread_for_slow_f)
    thread_for_slow_f.join()
    print ('End of all funcs')
```