# Как остановить поток, который работает с ОС

Tags: python, linux

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Разрабатываю систему автоматизированного тестирования. В ходе проведения теста мне нужно снять дамп. То есть в начале теста начал писать pcap, по окончанию перестал и сохранил.

Для снятия дампа создаю отдельный поток и флаг на остановку дампа

```
global still_dumping #The trigger to stop tcpdump.
still_dumping = False

if check_dump:
    still_dumping = True
    threading.Thread(target=dump(host_port)).start()  # Make a thread for tcpdump.
```

def dump(host_port):

```
if not still_dumping:
    os.system('killall -9 tcpdump')
    return

os.system('tcpdump -w testDump.pcap -i lo0 port ' + str(host_port) + ' &')
```

Однако воткнулся что при попадании на tcpdump поток зависает, потому что ничего формально tcpdump не останавливает и соответственно на killall он никогда не попадает.

Прошу помочь советом как его выдернуть из tcpdump.

Comment: Во-первых, `target=dump(host_port)` — вы вызываете функцию сразу же прямо здесь, а не в отдельном потоке

Comment: Во-вторых, тут вообще не надо потоки городить, просто используйте suprocess для запуска процессов в фоне

Comment: На сколько я понял threading. (....).start() создаёт поток и вызывает в нем функцию target. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: А как остановить suprocess по тригеру в данном случае? Если не сложно, приведите пожалуйста пример соответствующего кода с остановкой

Comment: «вызывает в нем функцию target» — да, если target это функция. Но вы запихнули в target не функцию, а результат вызова функции dump, а так как она ничего не возвращает, то и target получается None, то есть поток остаётся без функции

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался с suprocess и решил задачу через него.

Для следующих ищущих привожу сюда кусок кода

prc_dump = subprocess.Popen(['tcpdump', '-w', 'testDump.pcap',
                                     '-i', 'lo0', 'port', '8888'])

# Сделали что-то что нужно сделать

prc_dump.terminate()

Comment: Если вы разобрались, то лучше оформите как ответ.

Comment: @Amgarak а есть ли смысл, если вопрос изначально не про subprocess? А касательно упомянутого мной вызова функции внутри target это по сути дубликат множества других аналогичных вопросов, например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/723701

Comment: @andreymal возможно, но к сожалению, когда когда начинаешь с нуля не всегда просто разобраться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо! Разобрался с `suprocess` и решил задачу через него.
Для следующих ищущих привожу сюда кусок кода

```py
prc_dump = subprocess.Popen(['tcpdump', '-w', 'testDump.pcap', '-i', 'lo0', 'port', '8888']) 

//Сделали что-то что нужно сделать 
prc_dump.terminate() –
```